# Logging standard out with django and nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to debug an application I made with django and it works fine using django's manage.py, but when I use nginx some features do not work. I checked the error logs and they are empty, probably because I am catching all exceptions and sending them to standard out. Is there an easy way to see the output from the application with nginx?

Comment: How are you running django? WSGI?

Comment: Have you add the request error handler on your django config ?

Comment: My configuration is the same as listed here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSGI servers often disable stdout, I think because it can cause some sort of compatibility problems.  Django has built-in logging; I'd suggest using that instead of print statements.  It should both be easier to configure and also allow you to have more specificity in your logging, i.e. :

log.debug('only seen while debugging')

or

log.warn('this message might indicate a problem')

Relevant django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: Only mod_wsgi 2.X and older by default disabled use of stdout. This was to force people to write portable WSGI applications. No one cared, so mod_wsgi 3.X allows people to write stdout and so write non portable WSGI applications. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/04/wsgi-and-printing-to-standard-output.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, we're talking about nginx here, not Apache

Comment: I am well aware of that, but the statement 'WSGI servers often disable stdout' can only have been a reference to mod_wsgi for Apache because no other WSGI servers that I know of deliberately did something to try and stop you from using stdout. The only real exception was CGI scripts, which used stdout to communicate with the server, which is why mod_wsgi stopped use of stdout. That is, to ensure you wrote stuff that would still work with CGI/WSGI adapters that existed at the time.